# grepping the PID of a process - Unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep, pipe

I'm trying to execute the following command:

```
ps aux | grep com.scheduler.app.workermain | kill -15 [pid]
```

How can I obtain the `[pid]` (or list of `PID`) using `ps aux | grep "expression"` and pipe that to `kill`? There may be zero or many processes running the machine. This is part of an automated job, to ensure all the processes spun will be terminated. 
A sample line from the command line, when `ps aux | grep com.scheduler.app.workermain` is executed is:

```
jenkins  12373  1.1  4.2 2905440 173628 ?      Sl   19:28   0:05 java -Xmx600m -Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2-trace.xml -Dpid=foobar -Dipaddr=127.0.0.1 -cp build/classes:build/dependency/* com.scheduler.app.workermain testing.properties
```

Comment: Don't you have `pkill` available?

Comment: You might need to [exclude grep from your results](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/74185/5788)

Comment: 48 items when you search for `grep PID of a process [Unix]` here on S.O. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pkill` is used for exactly this purpose. How about:

```
pkill -15 -f com.scheduler.app.workermain
```

Also if you just want to grep for a PID you can use `pgrep`:

```
pgrep -f com.scheduler.app.workermain
```

[pkill man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)

Answer (score 2):

```
kill -15 $(ps aux | grep -i com.scheduler.app.workermain | awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is to use the `pidof` command:

```
kill $( pidof com.scheduler.app.workermain )
```

PS. You don't need to pass `-15` (or -TERM) to the `kill` command, as `SIGTERM` is the default signal sent.